# How to write dates validation in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am new to jquery, i am getting from date and to date with date picker.

Here i am trying to add validation, i want from date and to date between have 30 days only.

```
var fromDate = $("#from_txn_date").val();//2017-02-20 00:00:00
var toDate = $("#to_txn_date").val();//2017-06-20 00:00:00
```

above date have `4` months difference(approximately 120 days),but i want `fromDate` not greater than to `30` days.

```
if(fromDate > 30)
{
alert("**if**");
return false;
}else{
alert("**else**");
}
```

i tried my way but it's not working.

What's wrong in my code?

Comment: @Bhushan Kawadkar: this not duplicate question. Please care fully read my question

Comment: if i am not mistaken your problem is with date comparison. Here you are comparing date text instead of date object which results into wrong output. The link i referred to your question does the same thing of date conversion and comparision. Below answer posted by Okx is doing same thing. Let me know if any concerns.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```js
function submit() {
  var fromDate = new Date(document.getElementById("from").value);
  var toDate = new Date(document.getElementById("to").value);
  var millisecondsDiff = toDate - fromDate;
  if(millisecondsDiff > 2592000000) { // 30 days
    document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = "Range too big!";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = "Range is okay.";
  }
}
```

```html
<input id="from" type="date">
<input id="to" type="date">
<br/>
<button onclick="submit()">
  Submit
</button>
<div id="output">

</div>
```

Comment: i am getting with time also. here `millisecondsDiff ` getting `NaN`

Comment: @Durga When is it getting NaN? It may do that if the dates have not been selected.

Comment: but fromDate and toDates getting dates

Comment: i am getting date with time also